# POST json to URL from Android

Tags: android, json, http-post

I am trying to POST json to a URL from an android app. I went through every relevant answer I found here, but whatever I do, I am getting status code 406. I learned that means server isn't accepting the format of what I am sending, but I can't find what is wrong with what I am doing.

Here is the relevant code:

```
        @Override
        protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Log.w("json: ", formJSON().toString());

        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(formJSON().toString());
            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return httpResponse;
    }
```

I checked the JSON formed by my formJSON() method through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it was valid. BTW, the json I am expected to send is { String, String, String, String and String[] }

**EDIT:**

I found the answer myself. It seems during testing, I was sending some strings empty, so the POST was 406, "not in acceptable format". Once I tried filling everything manually, I got 200 back.

Comment: not sure but seems like mod_security issue in your server.you may check by running command SecFilterEngine off.BUT do this only for checking if the problem is the security filter, I discouraged to leave the filter off due to security reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your time but it seems the answer was much simpler :)